# Meteor markdown editor with embedded images / files

Tags: meteor, markdown

I want to be able to insert a file or image into a post written in markdown. I have a decent idea of how to do this using `collectionFS` and inserting the appropriate markdown text, but I was hoping that someone else has done this in a convenient smart-package.

Comment: For those of you who are simply looking for a Markdown editor package, I have written one called [d4nyll:epic](https://github.com/d4nyll/epic). If you'd like to see more features, I encourage you to open up an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do any of these do what you're looking for?

- https://atmospherejs.com/?q=markdown

I'm with you. I want to know if there's already something out there.

I've ended up implementing something I need only to find out there's already a smart package in atmosphere that does it better too many times!  lol

Comment: yeah, those don't looks so good. Guess I'll have to do it myself... :/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to reference images stored directly in your server. Place any images you want in the `Public` folder of your Meteor project. Even better `Public/Images`.

In your page, reference these images without the `Public` directory, e.g. `<img src="/Images/pic1.png">`